# Can I use BigQuery (GA4 data), which is unstructured data, as training data for EnterpriseSearch's Advanced LLM feature?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vertex-ai-search

I want to improve the accuracy of the Advanced LLM features in EnterpriseSearch. Can I use BigQuery (GA4 Export data), which is unstructured data, as training data?

I believe that Advanced LLM features is currently not supported when the data store is structured data.

If we use unstructured data as the data store, we can use Advanced LLM features, but we would like to know if there is a way to use BigQuery (GA4 Export data), which is structured data, for its answer summary content.

https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/activate-advanced-llm
https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/bring-embeddings

I have tried to set up structured data in the data store to use the Advanced LLM feature.
I remember there was a promotion in Google Cloud Next 23 that GA4 -> BigQuery -> EnterpriseSearch can use the generated AI feature.
I would like to know if this is feasible.

Also, the "Use custom embeddings" is deprecated in the documentation, but I would like to know if it is possible to use BigQuery data for training, for example.